# Spring Data throwing an EntityNotFoundException only with EntityGraph

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

I'm currently working on a bug that I can't explain, so I'm looking for some help here.

I'm using Spring Data to get my objects, and they are all managed by a column called "FlagCMS" which, if set to 'S' means that the object should not be linked to any other new one. It's a kind of soft-deleting that worked fine until now.

The classes are defined like this (minus a lot of unrelated code) :

Action.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "action")
@Where(clause = FlagCMS.WHERE_NOSOFTDELETED)
@NamedEntityGraphs({
    @NamedEntityGraph(name = "Action.maj", attributeNodes = {
            @NamedAttributeNode("ouvragesAction")
    }
})
public class Action {

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "action", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<OuvrageAction> ouvragesAction = new HashSet<>();

    @PreUpdate
    protected void cascadeDelete() {
        if (isDeleted()) {
            getAllCascades().stream().filter(Objects::nonNull).forEach(SoftDeletable::setDeleted);
        }
    }

    public Collection<OuvrageAction> getOuvragesAction() {
        return ouvragesAction;
    }

    public void setOuvragesAction(final Set<OuvrageAction> ouvragesAction) {
        this.ouvragesAction = ouvragesAction;
    }

    public List<Ouvrage> getOuvrages() {
        return ouvragesAction.stream().map(OuvrageAction::get).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

OuvrageAction.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ouvrage_action")
@Where(clause = FlagCMS.WHERE_NOSOFTDELETED)
@AttributeOverrides({
    @AttributeOverride(name = "id", column = @Column(name = "id_action_ouvrage"))
})
public class OuvrageAction extends AbstractReferentielAction<Ouvrage> {

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_ouvrage", nullable = false)
    private Ouvrage ouvrage;

    public OuvrageAction() {
        super();
    }

    public OuvrageAction(Ouvrage ouvrage, Action action) {
        super(action);
        this.ouvrage = ouvrage;
    }

    public Ouvrage getOuvrage() {
        return ouvrage;
    }

    public void setOuvrage(Ouvrage ouvrage) {
        this.ouvrage = ouvrage;
    }

}
```

Ouvrage.java

```
@Entity
@Immutable
@Table(name = "ouvrage")
@Where(clause = FlagCMS.WHERE_NOSOFTDELETED)
public class Ouvrage {

    @Column(name = "code")
    protected String code;

    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }
}
```

`WHERE_NOSOFTDELETED` is defined like this in FlagCMS.java :

```
public static final String WHERE_NOSOFTDELETED = "(flag_cms = 'C' or flag_cms = 'M')";
```

And I access the Action object using two different JpaRepositories defining similar methods, one keeping the lazy loading, and one using the EntityGraph :

```
@EntityGraph(value = "Action.maj", type = EntityGraphType.LOAD)
List<Action> findDistinctByCodeIn(List<String> codes);
```

and

```
List<Action> findDistinctByCodeIn(List<String> codes);
```

Now let's say I have an `Action` object linked to a `Ouvrage` object. The second have `FlagCMS` set to `S`. Using the lazy repository, everything is fine, I get my Actions and can access the `code` property of `Ouvrage` through it. Accessing the Action by using the repository with EntityGraph, I only get an EntityNotFoundException telling me that the `Ouvrage` object does not exist.

This does not seem consistent to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone come across the same issue, here's the trick : Turned out that the @Where condition is not propagating to items lazy loaded though link tables, but it does propagate when they are loaded with an entity graph.

So, if you really want to use an entity graph, you will have to exclude that particular property from the graph, and manually load all of them before losing your transaction.